# Magento2 hello world displaying blank screen

Tags: magento2, module, layout

I am trying to create a simple hello world module, I am able to successfully create and install the module but for some reason, my screen is showing up blank. But if I `echo` something in `controller` it shows up. Can anyone help me where exactly I am going wrong? Below is my code.

I have been following this [Tutorials](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_mvvm_mvc/)

```
-app
    -code
        -KK
            -OneStepCheckOut
                -Block
                    --Main.php
                -Controller
                    -OneStepCheckOut
                        --BillingAddress.php
                -etc
                    --module.xml
                    -frontend
                        --routes.xml
                -view
                   -frontend
                     -layout
                      --oneStepCheckOut_oneStepCheckOut_billingAddress.xml
                        -templates
                            --content.phtml
                --registration.php
```

**Controller:-**

```
<?php 

namespace kk\OneStepCheckout\Controller\OneStepCheckout;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
class BillingAddress extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $pageFactory;
    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {        
       // echo "In controller";
        $page_object = $this->pageFactory->create();
        return $page_object;
    }     
}

?>
```

**oneStepCheckOut_oneStepCheckOut_billingAddress.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="empty"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">        
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block 
            template="kk_OneStepCheckOut::content.phtml" 
            class="kk\OneStepCheckOut\Block\Main" 
            name="oneStepCheckOut" />
         </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Main.php:-**

```
<?php
namespace kk\OneStepCheckOut\Block;

class Main extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
   public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
?>
```

**Content.phtml:-**

```
<h1><?php echo "hello world"; ?></h1>
```

**routes.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="oneStepCheckOut" frontName="oneStepCheckOut">
            <module name="kk_OneStepCheckOut" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**module.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="kk_OneStepCheckOut" setup_version="0.0.1" />
</config>
```

Comment: Change file name `change 
 
`oneStepCheckOut_oneStepCheckOut_billingAddress.xml` to `onestepcheckout_onestepcheckout_billingaddress.xml`

Comment: Can use please  tell me the <html> body class of  this class

Comment: @AmitBera class is onestepcheckout-onestepcheckout-billingaddress page-layout-admin-1column

Comment: Thanks, by changing xml page name i got it.And can u pls post it as answer with an explanation why it has to be small letters. it would help other beginners like me. Thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

Change layout XML file name. Magento layout xml file name always in small letters.

replace it

```
oneStepCheckOut_oneStepCheckOut_billingAddress.xml
```

with file name

```
onestepcheckout_onestepcheckout_billingaddress.xml
```